# Not returning to cmd prompt after executing powershell command from cmd via psexec

Tags: powershell, cmd, psexec

I want to change the execution policy of a remote computer. After the command, the policy gets changed but control is not passed to cmd prompt.
the command i used:

```
C:\amp>psexec \\networkcomputer -u user -p password powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

In the cmd window it shows

```
C:\amp>psexec \\networkcomputer -u user -p password powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

PsExec v2.1 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

How to get out of it

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting prompted for confirmation, use the *-Force* switch and pipe a char into the command

```
psexec \\networkcomputer -u user -p password "echo . | powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force"
```

Comment: I did that, still its stuck

Comment: Its giving error
PsExec could not start echo . | powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force on networkcomputer:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: same issue. 
Starting echo on 172.16.61.156... 172.16.61.156... PsExec could not start echo on 172.16.61.156: The system cannot find the file specified.